# php downtown timer for logout and t

Tags: php, session, timer, logout, countdown

I have a question in php. I do need to make drop-down list with 2 choices. 
Ex: 1) 45sec
   2) 2 hours

to be the time of the session and after that the user will be logged out automatically.

- how to get the selected session time from the drop-down list in php.
- how to make and show the countdown time remaining in the title of the page.

I am new to php and hope get the best code for it

thanks

Comment: Send the selected choice trough an ajax-call to the server. The timer can be setup with javascript.

Comment: thanks but how I can get a code for this?

Comment: Maybe a bit of Google? Tons of examples all over the place.